# How to install php v8js on Mac?

Tags: php, reactjs, server-side-rendering

Hi i need php v8JS extension for ReactJs app. Can someone give me full installation instruction? I am using php 5.6 and Xampp.

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface this by saying: if you're looking for a shorter way to do this, it does not exist.

install the engine 
`$ brew install v8`

install dependency for the PECL extension 
`$ brew install autoconf`

install/configure PEAR and PECL:

- first download go-pear.phar file (you can also just download it manually using your browser) 
   
  `$ curl -O https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar`
- configure PEAR for installation:
  `$ php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar` 
   when prompted by the command above (the first three steps are to change the installation base and the last 3 are to change the binaries directory):

  1. type 1 and press enter.
  2. enter /usr/local/pear
  3. press enter.
  4. type 4 and press enter
  5. enter /usr/local/bin
  6. press enter.

update/upgrade PEAR/PECL:

`$ sudo pear channel-update pear.php.net`
`$ sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net`
`$ sudo pear upgrade-all`

Grab V8Js PECL Extension from github & install it

`$ cd ~` 
`$ mkdir tmp && cd tmp`
`$ git clone https://github.com/phpv8/v8js`
`$ cd v8js`
`$ phpize`
`$ ./configure CXXFLAGS="-Wno-c++11-narrowing"`
`$ make`
`$ make test #if this step fails you can try to install anyway. should work.`
`$ make install`

(note on Capitan users and the `make install` command: if you are getting an 'operation not permitted' error you will have to disable the system integrity protection as described [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-turn-off-the-rootless-in-OS-X-El-Capitan-10-11?share=1) - be sure to read on why this restriction is in place to begin with.)

make sure your php.ini file (located at: /etc/php.ini) has the following: `extension=v8js.so`

at this point, v8js should be available on the php command line, check: `$ php -i | grep v8js`

Bonus: the above should answer the question on how to get v8js installed but you have to go further to make it work on Mac's built-in Apache Server.

Apache httpd.conf (located at: /etc/apache2):
Uncomment the following line: 
`LoadModule php7_module libexec/httpd/libphp7.so`

Add the following to the httpd.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
# If php is turned on, we respect .php and .phps files.
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

# Since most users will want index.php to work we
# also automatically enable index.php
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

save the file. and restart the server: `sudo apachectl graceful` (or just start it if its not running)

Comment: Pear is compiling with the old version, how do you get it to compile with the new version?